# Obtaining a Total of Only Part of a Column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

The database I'm using shows the total number of debtors for every town for every quarter. 
Since there's 43 towns listed, there's 43 'total debtors' per quarter (30-Sep-17, etc).

My goal is to find the total number of debtors for every quarter (so theoretically, finding the sum of every 43 'total debtors' listed) but I'm not quite sure how.

I've tried using the sum() function, but I'm sure how to make it so it only adds the total quarter by quarter.

Here's what the database looks like and my attempt (I printed the first 50 rows just to provide an idea of what it looks like)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MENfq.png

Sorry in advance if the explanation was a bit unclear.

Comment: please post a sample data as text in the question and the desired output too. Images cant be copied and hence the question cannot be reproduced.

Comment: It might also help to show what you tried with `SUM()` and what specifically goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `groupby`. It's a nice pandas function to do exactly what you are trying to do. It groups the `df` according to whatever column you pick.

```
total_debtors_pq = df.groupby('Quarter end date')['Total number of debtors'].sum()
```

You can then extract the total for each quarter from `total_debtors_pq`.